# rspec `with` must have at least one argument. error after upgrade to 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I was upgrading our code base to use rspec 3.1.0 and was following the docs here:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/upgrade

One of the existing tests I get the following error after running transpec.

"`with` must have at least one argument. Use `no_args` matcher to set the expectation of receiving no arguments."

Here is  the test.

```
  it 'does something' do
    expect(my_method).to receive(:resource)
      .with { |path| path.include? 'test' }.and_return({})
  end
```

Does the new synatx not receive a block anymore?

Comment: What is `my_method`? What is the `resource` method defined on that? Please show us the code that you're testing.

Comment: What version of RSpec are you upgrading from?

Answer (score 1):

This was deprecated in version 2.99 and removed in rspec 3. You can see the details here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/377.

You can accomplish the same test with:

```
it 'does something' do
    expect(my_object).to receive(:resource).with(/test/).and_return({})
end
```